# For loop first in a dataframe then in a list - AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
UTC_date    maand   jaar    Eventtype       Eventtype1  Eventtype2   Eventtype3 Headline    Reportdescript  Narrative   content
1   2017-01-02  1   2017    Birdstrike      Operational Operations   Wildlife   Bird hit    Aircraft reports bird hit   
3   2017-01-06  1   2017    Near Birdstrike Operational Operations   Wildlife   birdstrike  NaN Possible birdstrike
6   2017-01-10  1   2017    Birdstrike      Operational Operations   Wildlife   bat hit
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
UTC_date    maand   jaar    Eventtype       Eventtype1  Eventtype2   Eventtype3 Headline    Reportdescript  Narrative   content  sort
1   2017-01-02  1   2017    Birdstrike      Operational Operations   Wildlife   Bird hit    Aircraft reports bird hit            bird
3   2017-01-06  1   2017    Near Birdstrike Operational Operations   Wildlife   birdstrike  NaN Possible birdstrike              bird
6   2017-01-10  1   2017    Birdstrike      Operational Operations   Wildlife   bat hit                                          bat


List = ['bird', 'rabit', 'rat', 'bat']
```

I want to check if one of the List values above is present in specific columns of a df, if a value is present I want it to be returned in a new column called `sort`, so I wrote the following code

```
for row in df.iloc[:,3:10]:
    for i in list:
        if row.str.contains(i):
            df['sort'] == i
return df
```

But I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-86295bce6dba> in <module>
      1 for row in df.iloc[:,3:10]:
      2     for i in birds:
----> 3         if row.str.contains(i):
      4             df['soort'] == i
      5 return df

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Dataframe info:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 1 to 6
Data columns (total 11 columns):

## Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   UTC_date        3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
1   maand           3 non-null      int64
2   jaar            3 non-null      int64
3   Eventtype       3 non-null      object
4   Eventtype1      3 non-null      object
5   Eventtype2      3 non-null      object
6   Eventtype3      3 non-null      object
7   Headline        3 non-null      object
8   Reportdescript  0 non-null      object
9   Narrative       3 non-null      object
10  content         3 non-null      object
dtypes: datetime64ns, int64(2), object(9)
memory usage: 312.0+ bytes

Comment: Will you please also show the code that you used to _create_ the dataframe? Right now all we can see is the `List`. We need the df too.

Comment: The df is read using read_excel function, I can't show it since it's large. I added the df info

Comment: One more question: what if none of the items in `List` match? What should the value of `sort` for that row be? NaN?

Comment: yes, it should be left blank/NaN